# Yii-Add things in a database, if a dropdown list shows no results

Tags: php, database, yii, yii-extensions, dropdown

I have two tables basically three tables, `Items`, `business` and `business_items`. In `items` table I have two fields `items_name` and `description` and in my `business` table I have `business_id`, `business_name`. In my `business_items` table I have `Items_id`, `business_id` as `foreign key` and an `image` field and a `price` field. Now these foreign keys fields are actually drop down list which are dynamic in nature. So as an owner, I will select items from `items` drop down list and a `business` from business drop down list.

**My problem**

As an admin, I can create items and businesses and all that stuff. But suppose an owner wants to create `business_items`, his business is already on the drop down list, but the `items` which he wants to add in his `business` does not found in the drop down list. So how can I make sure that, if no results found in the `items` drop down list, the searched item by owner automatically stores in `items` table and then he can add image and all the data saved in `business_items` table. I hope I explained my problem. I will explain more on ask. Feel free to ask.

Below is my `business_items` table `_form`

```
<?php
/* @var $this BusinessItemsController */
/* @var $model BusinessItems */
/* @var $form BSActiveForm */

$form = $this->beginWidget('bootstrap.widgets.BsActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'business-items-form',
    // Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
    // controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
    // There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
    // See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
    'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
    ),
)); 
?>
<p class="help-block">
     Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.
</p>
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'business_id'); ?>
<?php
$this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2', array(
    'name' => 'BusinessItems[business_id]',
    'data' => CHtml::listData(Business::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'business_name'), //the whole available list
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'placeholder'=>' search Business name?',
        'style' => 'width:530px',
    ),
));
?>
<div class="gap-small"> </div>
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'items_id'); ?>
<?php
$this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2', array(
    'name' => 'BusinessItems[items_id]',
    'data' => CHtml::listData(Items::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'item_name'), //the whole available list
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'placeholder'=>' search Item name?',
        'style' => 'width:530px',
    ),
));
?>
<div class="gap-small"> </div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <?php echo $form->textFieldControlGroup($model,'item_price',array('maxlength'=>60)); ?> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <?php echo BsHtml::activeFileField($model, 'image'); ?>  <!--  // by this we can upload image-->
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'image'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="gap-small"> </div><br/>
    <?php if ($model->isNewRecord != 1) : ?>
        <div class="row">
             <?php echo CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/img/'.$model->image, "image", array('width' => 250, 'height' => 250,)); ?>   <!--   Image shown here if page is update page-->
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>


<div class="gap-small"> </div>
<?php 
echo BsHtml::submitButton('Submit', array('color' => BsHtml::BUTTON_COLOR_PRIMARY)); 

$this->endWidget();
?>
```

Comment: You should use rules() with scenario to be sure.

Comment: is there any extension available ?